# insert a row in pandas dataframe based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, append

Insert a row in pandas df based on another column

Sample df

| count | A |
| --- | --- |
| yes | 23 |
| yes | 23 |
| yes | 40 |
| yes | 40 |
| yes | 40 |

result I want -> insert 'result' at the end of similar A values

| count | A |
| --- | --- |
| yes | 23 |
| yes | 23 |
| result |  |
| yes | 40 |
| yes | 40 |
| yes | 40 |
| result |  |

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this logic

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"count": ["yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes"],
                   "A": [23, 23, 40, 40, 40]})

new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["count", "A"])

# df['shift'] = df['A'].shift() != df['A']
# df['cumsum'] = df['shift'].cumsum()

for k, v in df.groupby((df['A'].shift() != df['A']).cumsum()):

    new_df = new_df.append(v[["count", "A"]], ignore_index=True)
    new_df = new_df.append({"count": "result", "A": None}, ignore_index=True)

print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
    count     A
0     yes    23
1     yes    23
2  result  None
3     yes    40
4     yes    40
5     yes    40
6  result  None
```

Comment: It's removing the NaN values in column A, we have to add a 'result' row after a group of NaN values also

Comment: you can set `NaN` to `-1` and after adding the `result` set `-1` to  `NaN`.